# How to send a multilingual content message?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a message containing Arabic text content. For sure it's available in JavaMail API, but how ? What if i want to write in both English and Arabic languages, is that possible? then how ?

//////I tried the following but didn't work:

```
message.setContent(messageText,"text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
message.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","Base64");
```

//////The output always of :

```
message.getSubject() is ==> ??????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll also need to use the MimeMessage setSubject method that allows you to specify a charset.  Using UTF-8 should work with most mail readers these days.  You do need to be sure you're using Java Strings with the correct Unicode characters to begin with.  If you're reading the data from somewhere, there's lots of opportunities to mess up the character encodings and conversions.